# How to display Logged in User details from a list in SharePoint with Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, display-form, powerapps-forms

I am creating a simple Power apps application, I need help on how to display a list content of logged in User.

Example, If the logged in User name matches the list field titled **Name** then display contents of that row.

Comment: What is the data type of "Name" field? Single line of text / person or group field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the user details like Full name, Email, etc. in PowerApps using **[User()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-user)** function.

So, all you have to do is filter a SharePoint list data source using this function based on your requirement.

**If Name is Single Line of Text Field in List**:

```
Filter('SharePoint List', Name = User().FullName)
```

**If Name is Person or Group Field in List**:

```
Filter('SharePoint List', 'Name'.DisplayName = User().FullName)
```

OR

```
Filter('SharePoint List', 'Name'.Email = User().Email)
```

**Note**: It is best practice to use the `Email` for filtering data sources as multiple users can have same full name/display name within organization.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was really helpful, one more question where do I place this filter in order to automatically display the item in the forms display mode.

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Comment: If you are using a gallery to show the list items then you can set the "Items" property of gallery with this. Or you can save the filtered list items in a collection variable and use it wherever you want.